# Removing new lines from a text file in Notepad++

Tags: regex, wildcard, ultraedit

I need to replace all the strings that look like this:

```
<\name>
```

for a <kbd>Tab</kbd>

name can be anything from 3 to 15 characters long

I've managed to do it by doing search `<\.*>` replace with `\t`

Now I need to replace any new lines with a single <kbd>Tab</kbd> i.e. remove the new line.  For some reason Ultraedit doesn't recognise the new line in the search box. I've used `\r` and `\n`, but none of them works.

This is an example of the file, after the search and replace:

```
               1    
             101    
           54651    
          150756    
             282    
             506    
             398    
            2759    
         59.62  
           35737    
              65
```

I want to get all that in a single line separated by tabs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try with `\r\n` ?

Comment: I've just done it.  It worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Hint: When using Perl regular expression in UltraEdit and use a search expression which should contain line terminator, use `(?:\r?\n|\r)` for line terminator as this expression works for files with DOS or UNIX or MAC terminated lines, i.e. for all common line termination types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Notepad++ I'll assume you're on Windows.

This means the text files you're using were likely created on a DOS type system (including Windows...) and therefore terminate lines with `\r\n` rather than a single `\n` like you might find on a UNIX system.

Try searching for that instead.

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ (I'm using windows) This does the trick:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select all then press ctrl+j after that replace spaces with "\t".
(Do not include double inverter commas)